# Proving formulas with products of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, products

While digging through my old notes, I stumbled upon some formulas involving multiplication of Fibonacci numbers that I discovered about 7 years ago (being fascinated with Fibonacci numbers at the time). I don't know if they are worth any attention. Anyway, first I would like to prove them, but I don't know how to do it. Here are the formulas:

$$
F_a \cdot F_b ~=~ F_{ \lfloor{{a+b} \over {2}}\rfloor } \cdot F_{ \lceil{{a+b} \over {2}}\rceil } ~-~ (-1)^a \cdot  F_{ \lfloor{{b-a} \over {2}}\rfloor } \cdot F_{ \lceil{{b-a} \over {2}}\rceil }
\tag{a}
$$
$$
{F_n}^2 ~=~ \sum _{i=1} ^{n} F_{i-1} \cdot F_i ~+~ (n \bmod 2)
\tag{b}
$$
$$
2 \cdot F_n \cdot F_{n+1} ~=~ {F_{n+1}}^2 + {F_n}^2 - {F_{n-1}}^2 ~=~ {F_{n+2}}^2 - {F_{n+1}}^2 - {F_n}^2 ~=~ {F_n}^2 + F_{2n}
\tag{c}
$$
$$
F_{2m+1} \cdot F_{2n} ~=~ {F_{n+m+1}}^2 - {F_{n+m}}^2 + {F_{n-m}}^2 - {F_{n-m-1}}^2
\tag{d}
$$

Formula (a) can be split into the following cases:
\begin{align}
F_{2m} \cdot F_{2n} &= {F_{m+n}}^2 - {F_{m-n}}^2
\\
F_{2m+1} \cdot F_{2n+1} &= {F_{m+n+1}}^2 + {F_{m-n}}^2
\\
F_{2m+1} \cdot F_{2n} &= F_{m+n} \cdot F_{m+1+n} - F_{m-n} \cdot F_{m+1-n}
= F_{n+m} \cdot F_{n+m+1} + F_{n-m} \cdot F_{n-m-1}
\end{align}

Formula (b) has 2 cases:
$$
{F_{2n}}^2 ~=~ \sum _{i=1} ^{2n} F_{i-1} \cdot F_i
\\
{F_{2n+1}}^2 ~=~ \sum _{i=1} ^{2n+1} F_{i-1} \cdot F_i ~+~ 1
$$

Note that some of these formulae work with the [*negafibonacci*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_negative_integers) sequence.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ have the same parity or not?

Comment: Floor/Ceiling wouldn't be necessary if they had the same parity

Comment: @MarkBennet No, either $a$ or $b$ or both can be even or odd.

Comment: The point is that the formulae differ with parity, so are just a way of writing related formulae in an apparently neat way. There are four cases $a$ even or odd, and $b$ even or odd. They are related, but I think it is easier to write them separately without the floor/ceiling if you are trying to prove them.

Comment: I've added separate formulae for all cases.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, these are easiest to understand using the Binet formula $F_n = \frac{1}{s-t}(s^n - t^n)$, where $s,t$ are the positive and negative roots of $X^2 - X - 1 = 0$.

This reduces these equations to facts about polynomials in $s$ and $t$.  For example:

$$(s^{m+n}-t^{m+n})^2 - (s^{2m} - t^{2m})(s^{2n} - t^{2n}) $$
$$ = s^{2m}t^{2n}+s^{2n}t^{2m} - 2(st)^{m+n}$$
$$ = (st)^{2n}(s^{m-n}-t^{m-n})^2$$

Since $st=1$, it follows (from division by $(s-t)^2$) that $F_{m+n}^2 -F_{2m} F_{2n} = F_{m-n}^2$.  Your equations (a), (c), and (d) are easily dispatched this way, even for the "negafibonaccis".

For (b), we can use (a) to form a telescoping sum:

$$F_n^2 - F_{n-1} F_n = F_n (F_n - F_{n-1}) = F_n F_{n-2}$$
$$ = F_{n-1}^2 + (-1)^n$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^n F_{i-1} F_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (F_i^2 - F_{i-1}^2 - (-1)^i) = F_n^2 + (n\bmod 2)$$

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting! Now I must read more about the Binet formula to understand your approach :)

Comment: @Adam It's also a very good way to motivate the study of the Lucas numbers, which satisfy $L_n = s^n + t^n$.

Comment: @Adam Let me add: by some general theory about recurrences, any sequence satisfying $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n$ must be of the form $a_n = A\cdot s^n + B\cdot t^n$ for constants $A$ and $B$.  So the Binet formula is more intuitive than it looks.